# Running DSpace with replica secondary server

Tags: dspace

Would there be any issues running DSpace on multiple servers with a load balancer in front? I would like to divert connections from harvesters and crawlers to a secondary server to reduce load on the primary server, with the secondary server having a read-only replica of the database as the backend.

Otherwise, how do implementations handle traffic from harvesters and web crawlers/bots without them negatively impacting the user experience and performance of DSpace?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need shared storage for the assetstore(s).

I've never tried it, but I see only one issue with running multiple instances against the same repository, and it wouldn't apply if only one instance can write the current assetstore.  Each submitted file is copied into the assetstore under a random name.  The uniqueness of these names is ultimately dependent on internal details of java.rmi.dgc.VMID, which is supposed to be unique across JVMs.  Whether it is unique across multiple hosts, I don't know.  The likelihood that two concurrent deposits on different servers would create the same bitstream ID is a number I wouldn't want to calculate.

If you had multiple *writable* instances, you could configure a different active assetstore on each, **with distinct assetstore numbers**.

I think most of the thought about crawlers has been given to keeping them from polluting the statistics without rejecting them outright.  There is a Tomcat CrawlerSessionManagerValve that tries to force all detected agents into a single session, but that may not work anymore in DSpace 7 because its session management is very different.